# failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/easy-instagram.git'

Tags: heroku, angular

I have generated my angualr2 app using `ng new project` command, and now i am trying to put my project on heroku, unfortunatly, I faced with an error when i pushed my code with `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 65, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Writing objects: 100% (65/65), 363.09 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 65 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.6
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:
remote:        > qminder@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_a0673d10d05036142a147f64099bd6fb
remote:        > typings install
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: typings: not found
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_a0673d10d05036142a147f64099bd6fb/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_a0673d10d05036142a147f64099bd6fb/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_a0673d10d05036142a147f64099bd6fb/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v5.11.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
remote:        npm ERR! file sh
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote:        npm ERR! qminder@0.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
remote:        npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the qminder@0.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the qminder package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     typings install
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs qminder
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls qminder
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_a0673d10d05036142a147f64099bd6fb/npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to easy-instagram.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/easy-instagram.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/easy-instagram.git'
```

So, **is there anything that i can add to my project to fix this problem?**

I have mannually added the node version to my config.json file, but it still complains with the same error:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1",
    "node":"4.4.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **Heroku** doesn't install your `devDependencies`
There are two possible variants how to fix it:

- Move `typings` inside `dependencies`:

`"dependencies": {
    ...
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    ...`

OR

- `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` needs to be set to `false` for **Heroku** to install `devDependencies`